# Padding on Button Not Working Locally, but Working on JSFiddle

Tags: html, css

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/091mmv9w/2/
Here's my HTML:

```
  <div class="homepageInfo">
<h3 class="InternetServices">Internet Services</h3>
<div class="infoblurb">
<p> With speeds as high as 60 Mbps we offer a fast, yet affordable Internet!  Packages are available for residential and business accounts!!  <a href="contact/">  Connect with us!<br></a></p>
</div>
<div class="buttonposition">
<button type="button" class="btn btntruespeed">Select Your Package!</button>
</div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.infoblurb {
  width: 145px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.buttonposition {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
.homepageInfo {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 30px;
}
.InternetServices {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Why isn't this working?  I'm thinking it's an inherit issue, but I don't know where.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem, but please put the solution in an Answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issue! I just changed my CSS to homepageInfo Button and that moved it.